# Generate a custom report with parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, parameters, reportbuilder, rdl

I have created a .RDL with ReportBuilder 3.0. This RDL contains a dataset and a datasource. The dataset has its own query. This RDL contains some parameters.

What i want to do is:
From a WPF application, take this RDL, put some data in the parameters, create the report and save the report.

This RDL is a local file added to the project.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDL report is meant to be published on Reporting Services server.

I believe what you need is rdlc report that you can use locally.

How to create a report:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx

Passing parameters programmatically:
http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.in/2012/01/passing-parameters-to-rdlc.html

Comment: This looks good, but how can I use custom querys? I don't want to add a whole table to a dataset, but just some data from different tables.

Comment: You pass data via dataset in

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.

Just get the data you need using Ado.net and then pass the resulting dataset as a report parameter. The constructor of ReportDataSource accepts [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd461468(v=vs.100).aspx), so you can pass any data you need.